# how can I access a specific index of an array in the setState method in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example if a state is like this

```
state={
   reports:[{name:'nadib',age:23},{name:'nadib2',age:24}]
}
```

how can I change `nadib2` to john with setState method?

Comment: What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `functional setState` syntax and create a copy using `map` to prevent mutation of the current state.

Then inside the loop, return the original object if you do not wish to modify. For the object that you need to modify, you could find it with a ternary operator and copy all existing keys, optionally modifying the other keys like shown.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
   return { 
            reports : prevState.reports.map(item => 
                       item.name === 'nadib2' ? ({...item, name: 'john'}) : item) 
          };
});
```